# Complexity for determining whether a given metric space is hyperconvex?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-complexity, convex-geometry, metric-spaces

Suppose I am given a finite metric space as a distance matrix. What is the complexity of determining whether this metric space is [hyperconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_metric_space)?

Definition: A metric space is said to be *hyperconvex* if it is convex, and its closed balls have the (binary) Helly property. That is, if any family of closed balls intersects pairwise, then the entire family intersects.

I did some Googling, but so far have only found results about the theoretical properties of such spaces, not on matters related to computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finite metric spaces with more than two points cannot be hyperconvex, because they cannot be convex.
Just take the two closest points in the metric space. There are no points between them. Therefore, the space is not convex.

Comment: doh! thanks for the sanity check... i guess a more sensible question would be whether balls satisfy the helly property, since that is sufficiently general